# How to access updated DAO recordset properties during a transaction?

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I am developing an application in Access which uses transaction processing in DAO. I use a class to represent a body of data to be imported from another source. Among other things, this class houses a dictionary of recordsets, each of which has a new record added or an existing record edited depending on whether another record exists with the same primary key or not. I create an instance of this class from another procedure in a normal code module and use the properties and methods of the class to perform analysis and finalize the data extract.

In one procedure I want to subsequently edit the most recently added or edited record for each recordset in order to augument what has already been done to those records via the class' methods. The problem is that after a transaction has begun processing the .Recordcount property doesn't appear to update until the transaction has been committed, and it doesn't look like I can set a bookmark to the newly-added/edited record prior to committing it. The latter issue throws a "No Current Record" error when trying to set a bookmark to a record that has just been added (the Recordcount property is still at 0).

Am I correct in the understanding that DAO bookmarks are not a viable way of recalling a record that may have been added prior to committing a transaction? Is there another better way of doing this, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that although the .Bookmark property was not available during the transaction the .LastModified property was, which is a bookmark pointer to the record I wanted to access anyway. I simply went from:

```
Private Sub Test()

dim vBookmark as Variant
dim wsp as Workspace
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
dim rs2 as DAO.Recordset

set wsp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable)

wsp.BeginTrans

'... Make some record active

vBookmark = rs.Bookmark 
'Note: ^ Error is thrown here when recordset has 0 records

'... Later

set rs2.Bookmark = vBookmark

wsp.CommitTrans

End Sub
```

To this:

```
Private Sub Test()

dim vBookmark as Variant
dim wsp as Workspace
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
dim rs2 as DAO.Recordset

set wsp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable)

wsp.BeginTrans

'... Make some record active

vBookmark = rs.LastModified
'Note: ^ Correctly stores bookmark even during an uncommitted transaction

'... Later

set rs2.Bookmark = vBookmark

wsp.CommitTrans

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference a record but are unable to via bookmark, hang onto the data by using a static array of type variant. Use one of the elements in the array to act as a bookmark of sorts. To process the array to find your bookmark, keep a static variable with the index value of the bookmark in the array.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: Thanks for the input @RICHARD Pietrzak. I had thought about this but would more likely use a collection or dictionary since they are indexed for quick lookups. Even so, I am trying to avoid using index numbers since they can change if records are added or deleted from the recordset. I suppose I can create procedures (or better yet, methods in the class) for adding/deleting records which reindex the array, but seems like there may be a more efficient way to do it.I will give this or some sort of hybrid a shot and let you know how it goes. If anyone else has any bright ideas, please let me know!